# Reference Same Class within a Class

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to create some simple classes for a project that I am working on.  I am running into a problem with circular references, and I am not sure what is the solution here.   I understand my class is likely designed wrong, so any overall recommendations on how to do this correctly would be appreciated.

I chopped the code down to the bare essentials to show how I am building this class and references.

```
Public Class Utilities
    Public Class Result
        Public Success As Boolean = False
    End Class
End Class

Public Class Customer
    Public Class Contact

        Public Class ContactList : Inherits Utilities.Result
            Public Contact As Contact()
        End Class

        Public ID As String
        Public Created As Date
        Public CreatedBy As New Contact

        Public Shared Function Search(oInput As Contact) As ContactList

            Dim oOutput As New ContactList

            ReDim oOutput.Contact(500)

            While oDataReader.Read()
                oOutput.Success = True
                oOutput.Contact(i) = New Contact()
                oOutput.Contact(i).ID            = oDataReader("ID").ToString()
                oOutput.Contact(i).Created       = oDataReader("Created").ToString()
                oOutput.Contact(i).CreatedBy.ID  = oDataReader("CreatedByID").ToString()
                i = i + 1
            End While
            oDataReader.Close()
            ReDim Preserve oOutput.Contact(i-1)

            Return oOutput      

        End Function        
End Class
```

When I run this code, I get the error:  Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.

Comment: `Class Contact` has a member `CreatedBy` which itself creates new a `Contact`:  which has a member `CreatedBy` which creates a new `Contact` which....

Comment: Which would be "fine" _if_ it didn't initialize it to a new instance.

Comment: StackOverflowExceptions are caused by infinite recursion. If you use your debugger (ie. visual studio) and step through the code (as it executes) you will notice that a method will be repeated in an infinite loop. That will be the culprit. If you have already observed this then shame on you for not posting that information in the question.

Comment: Or by simply looking at the call-stack in the exception.

Comment: ^--- to add to that. If you have an Exception always include in your question the `Message`, the `Type`, the `StackTrace`, and repeat this recursively across `InnerException`s all the way down.

Comment: Yes, I did run it thru the debugger in VS, and saw that it was looping on the CreatedBy in the Class.   This is what I meant by circular reference in my description.   Sorry if I was not clear on that.  What i am having a problem with is how to fix this.  I am assuming I made some sort of bad design decision, but I am not sure what would be the correct one to be able to reference the same class within itself.

Comment: Fix = remove the `New` keyword: `Public CreatedBy As Contact`

Comment: Here is the full exception from Visual Studio:  System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147023895
  Message=Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.
  InnerException:

Comment: That fixed it.  When I removed the New, it loaded everything just fine.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Rather creating class in class in class can you have all classes created individually. You can have code like this:

```
Public Class Utilities
    Dim myResult as Result

    Public Shared Function Search(oInput As Contact) As ContactList

        Dim oOutput As New ContactList

        ReDim oOutput.Contact(500)

        While oDataReader.Read()
            oOutput.Success = True
            oOutput.Contact(i) = New Contact()
            oOutput.Contact(i).ID            = oDataReader("ID").ToString()
            oOutput.Contact(i).Created       = oDataReader("Created").ToString()
            oOutput.Contact(i).CreatedBy.ID  = oDataReader("CreatedByID").ToString()
            i = i + 1
        End While
        oDataReader.Close()
        ReDim Preserve oOutput.Contact(i-1)
        'you can store the array to myResult here for further use. and to reduce the Search function usage.

        Return oOutput      

    End Function        
End Class
Public Class Result : Inherits ContactList
        Dim Success As Boolean = False
    End Class

Public Class Customer
    Dim myContact as Contact 
    Dim myContactList as ContactList
End Class

Public Class ContactList 
        Public Contact As Contact()
End Class

Public Class Contact
    Public ID As String
    Public Created As Date
    Public CreatedBy As String 
    'CreatedBy should have Contact ID only as you are using the ID field of CreatedBy contact
    'Where ever you are referencing the CreatedBy field you can have the ID string of the CreatedBy Contact 
    'On which you can lookup the data you needed. 

    Public Function setCreatedBy (_CreatedBy As String)
    CreatedBy = _CreatedBy
    End Function
End Class
```